# Writing single page logging tool in php

Tags: php, mysql

Im making a small php webpage which I plan to use to track on which subjects a helpdesk receives calls. My database has 3 important fields: id, name, and amount for each subject.

On my page I have a  form with a dropdown list where you select a type of call and click submit. The idea is that every time you click submit the page reloads and the amount in the database for the chosen id is heightened by 1.

The form gives me the id and name for each call:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<select class="select" id="calltype" name="calltype">
<?php 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=".$row["ID"].">".$row["NAAM"]."</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
</select></br>
<input class="input" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This part works, if I echo $_POST['calltype'] I get the correct ID. What I can't get to work is the update statement which I want to heighten the counter, like:

```
if(isset($_POST['calltype']{
mysqli_query("UPDATE calls SET amount=(amount+1), WHERE id = $_POST['calltype']");
}
```

How would I go about this? I tried several methods but can't get it to work

Comment: Are there any errors in your error log?

Comment: For one thing, your code is wide open to SQL injection.  So we don't know what you're actually trying to execute against the database.  Additionally, you're not checking for errors from the database.  If `mysqli_query()` is returning `false` then you need to find out what the error is.  The database is probably trying to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: (Hint: You have an errant comma in your SQL statement.  Looks like a typo.)

Comment: If you are learning PHP and database access then I suggest using PDO rather then mysqli. Why? It hides a lot of the low-level 'nuts and bolts' that you need to use with mysqli. For example,  All the ORM's are built on top of it. I recommend: [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) for understanding and using PDO correctly.

Answer (score 0):

besides for the extra comma, interpolation with the POST array like this is risky. maybe try:

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE calls SET amount=(amount+1) WHERE id = " . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['calltype']) . " ;");
```